# Use MobX with React Context while using Mobx Persist Store?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react, mobx-persist

Originally, I was using `new CounterStore` inside `React.createContext()`

## context.ts

```
import React from 'react'
import { stores, PersistState, CounterStore } from '@/store/index'
import type { ICounterStore } from '@/types/index'

export const FrameItContext = React.createContext<ICounterStore>(new CounterStore())
export const useCounterStore = () => React.useContext(FrameItContext)
```

Then I started using [Mobx Persist Store](https://github.com/quarrant/mobx-persist-store/) in my app.

## persist.ts

```
import { persistence, StorageAdapter } from 'mobx-persist-store'
import { CounterStore } from '@/store/index'

const read = (name: string): Promise<string> =>
    new Promise((resolve) => {
        const data = localStorage.getItem(name) || '{}'
        console.log('got data: ', data)
        resolve(data)
    })

const write = (name: string, content: string): Promise<Error | undefined> =>
    new Promise((resolve) => {
        localStorage.setItem(name, content)
        console.log('write data: ', name, content)
        resolve(undefined)
    })

export const PersistState = persistence({
    name: 'CounterStore',
    properties: ['counter'],
    adapter: new StorageAdapter({ read, write }),
    reactionOptions: {
        // optional
        delay: 2000,
    },
})(new CounterStore())
```

And I changed my code to use `PersistState` instead of `new CounterStore()`

## context.ts

```
import React from 'react'
import { stores, PersistState, CounterStore } from '@/store/index'
import type { ICounterStore } from '@/types/index'

export const FrameItContext = React.createContext<ICounterStore>(PersistState)
export const useCounterStore = () => React.useContext(FrameItContext)
```

It only logs `got data: {}` to the console. The `write` function never gets called.

Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Coincidentally, a simple Counter example on Codesandbox works perfectly fine → https://codesandbox.io/s/mobx-persist-store-4l1dm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example above works on a simple Chrome extension or a web app but just doesn't seem to work with my specific application so I wrote a manual implementation of saving to LocalStorage.

Use `toJSON()` on the store to keep track of which properties should be saved:

```
toJSON() {
    const { color, counter } = this
    return {
        color,
        counter,
    }
}
```

And add the `localStorage` logic just below the `constructor()`. First, check if the `localStorage` contains latest value & return it, if it does.

If there is nothing saved, then save it inside `localStorage`.

```
constructor() {
    ...
    const name = "CounterStore"
    const storedJson = localStorage.getItem(name)
    if (storedJson) Object.assign(this, JSON.parse(storedJson))
    autorun(() => {
        localStorage.setItem(name, JSON.stringify(this))
    })
}
```

Codesandbox → https://codesandbox.io/s/mobx-persist-store-manual-implementation-vm38r?file=/src/store.ts